# Spatial join string attributes for intersecting polygons (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have seen tutorials for the 'Spatial Join' tool that allows me to summarize statistical data for overlapping polygons on two separate layers. But I simply want to append a 'String' attribute from an underlying layer to polygon features on an overlying layer.

Specifically: I have a layer of 'land uses'; and a layer of 'buildings'. I would like to attach the 'land use [string]' attribute for a particular 'land use' polygon (on the land-use layer) to all the buildings (smaller polygons on the 'buildings layer') that intersect with that specific land use polygon.

Can somehow tell me what tool or script to use with QGIS? (And how to use it.)

Comment: But after the spatial join, did you try merging the two fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can join whole attribute tables of both layers based on intersection of features with **Join attributes by location** from menu `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attributes by location` or from processing toolbox. As `Attribute summary` set *Takes attributes of the first located feature*.

[image]

Comment: I never thanked you. But this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, then you should "accept" the answer by clicking on the check-mark.